# mysqld crashing almost every hour - mysqld invoked oom-killer -

Tags: mysql, centos

I am running wordpress on a centOS digital ocean droplet

my mysql keeps crashing almost every hour -- with an out of memory error

manually restarting mysqld brings it back up via **sudo service mysqld restart**

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

here are my configurations and logs around the time of the crash:

**/etc/my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
max_connections         = 50
wait_timeout            = 3600
interactive_timeout     = 3600
open_files_limit        = 2048
table_open_cache        = 1024
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
max_heap_table_size     = 256M
tmp_table_size          = 256M
key_buffer_size         = 128M
join_buffer_size        = 2M
sort_buffer_size        = 2M
read_buffer_size        = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 256K
```

**/var/log/messages:**

```
/var/log/messages:Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x6200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
/var/log/messages:Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: ? virtballoon_oom_notify+0x25/0x70 [virtio_balloon]
/var/log/messages:Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: oom_kill_process.cold.29+0xb/0x10
/var/log/messages:Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
/var/log/messages:Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: oom_reaper: reaped process 11402 (mysqld), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

**journalctl**

```
 Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x6200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: mysqld cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 11418 Comm: mysqld Kdump: loaded Not tainted 4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.x86_64 #1

    Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 11402 (mysqld) total-vm:1525956kB, anon-rss:419744kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: oom_reaper: reaped process 11402 (mysqld), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL 8.0 database server.
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos systemd[1]: Starting MySQL 8.0 database server...
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos mysql-check-socket[12938]: Socket file /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock exists.
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos mysql-check-socket[12938]: No process is using /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock, which means it is a garbage, so it will be removed automatically
Sep 16 17:51:39 centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 17:51:39 centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score -1):

Comment out sort_buffer_size and join_buffer_size. Changing those is almost always counterproductive.

How many temporary tables (implicit or explicit) do you ever have at any one time? If more than very few and they are big you will need to reduce the max_heap_table_size.